# Understand the day in a life of an Apache log message in modern Linux system

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd, logs

How does a day in a life of an Apache log message in modern `systemd` based Linux system look like? I would expect it to be something like that:

1. Apache daemon writes a log message using `syslog(3)`
2. this log message is written to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`
3. `systemd-journald` reads the log message from
   `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`
4. `systemd-journald` writes it to `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`
5. `rsyslogd` or `syslog-ng` listen on `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`,
   get the message and then process it based on their configuration

Am I missing something? Is it possible that Apache logs(for example access log messages) directly to files, bypassing the whole logging system altogether?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the Apache configuration. As documented in [mod_log_config](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog), `CustomLog` can be used to send logs directly a file or pipe them to a command. That command could in turn pipe the contents on to a `syslog` daemon or even into the `systemd journal`.

The not-yet-released Apache 2.5 allows logging directly to `systemd` via [`mod_journald`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_journald.html).